# What are the equivalents of magento 1.x models in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, php

I am new to magento2 and I am finding it very difficult to get the regular code snippets right in the new version. So, please help me out here and explain the equivalents of the following snippets in magento2:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Mage::getModel('sales/order');
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
Mage::getModel('cart/quote');
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id);
```

I hope this question will help all the new magento 2 developers to find relative queries all at one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**M1**

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id);
Mage::getModel('sales/order');
Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

**M2**

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory 
\Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory
\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
```

for getting the colloection

```
protected $_productloader; 

  public function __construct(....\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productloader,
    array $data = []

    ) {

     .....

        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;

        ....
    }
   public function getCollection()
   {
    $productCollection = $this->_productloader->create()->load(); 
   }
```

for current product load

```
    protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
       ....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
       ...
    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        ..........
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }
```

get category collection  as op asked

```
    protected $_categorycollection; 

  public function __construct(....\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Categroy\CollectionFactory $_categorycollection,
    array $data = []

    ) {

     .....

        $this->_categorycollection = $_categorycollection;

        ....
    }
   public function getCollection()
   {
    return $categoryCollection = $this->_categorycollection->create()->load(); 
   }
```

Comment: Do I have to always define the path?
Can I store these paths in global constant and then use them?

Comment: you have to add in your __construct as mention in example...

Comment: Lets say I need to call category collection in my block, how'd I do it?

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo added the category collection example too

Comment: Can you also add how can we use dependency injection?